# Парсинг vk api_

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, парсер

Доброго времени суток.
Заранее прошу прощения за нубство, только недавно начал пробовать себя в программировании, выбрал Java, собственно на Java и хочу попробовать отпарсить ВК.
Собственно: стоит задача вытянуть список университетов, факультетов и кафедр каждого города России из ВК. По идее, нужно использовать следующее: database.getUniversities / database.getFaculties / database.getChairs
Список id всех городов есть. (Например: Москва (id 1); Санкт-Петербург (id 2);)

В гугле есть примеры с парсингом групп, стен, списком аудиозаписей и т.д., но это немного не то.
Подскажите, как правильно и с чего начать?

Comment: Попробуйте вот это использовать: https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK

Comment: Хотелось бы поконкретнее немного.

Answer (score 3):

1. Открывайте [доку к API](https://vk.com/dev/methods)
2. Находите нужный [метод](https://vk.com/dev/database.getUniversities)
3. Подставьте нужные значения
4. Отправьте составленный запрос.
5. Получите ответ.
6. Распарсите его каким угодно способом.

Пример запроса:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/database.getUniversities?country_id=1&city_id=1
```

Ответ будет такой:

```
{"response":[712,{"id":2,"title":"МГУ"},{"id":86,"title":"АПИ при ИГиП РАН"},{"id":87,"title":"Финансовый университет (бывш. ГУМФ)"},{"id":88,"title":"АГПС МЧС России"},{"id":89,"title":"АГЗ МЧС России"},{"id":90,"title":"АМИ"},{"id":92,"title":"РАНХиГС при Президенте РФ (АНХ при Правительстве РФ, РАГС при Президенте РФ)"},{"id":93,"title":"МИГУП (бывш. АПУ)"},{"id":94,"title":"АТиСО"},{"id":95,"title":"АУ МВД РФ"},{"id":96,"title":"АФПС РФ"},{"id":97,"title":"АФСБ РФ (бывш. ВШ КГБ СССР им. Дзержинского)"},{"id":98,"title":"АХИ им. В. С. Попова"},{"id":99,"title":"АЭИ"},{"id":100,"title":"АЭиУ"},{"id":101,"title":"АРБИ"},{"id":102,"title":"ВА РВСН им. Петра Великого (бывш. ВА им. Дзержинского)"},{"id":103,"title":"ВИУ МО РФ"},{"id":105,"title":"ВУНЦ ВВС ВВА им. проф. Н. Е. Жуковского и Ю. А. Гагарина (бывш. ВВИА)"},{"id":106,"title":"ВУМО РФ (бывш. ВПА им. Ленина)"},{"id":107,"title":"ВУРХБЗ"},{"id":108,"title":"ИСВ (бывш. ВУ)"},{"id":109,"title":"ВАВТ"},{"id":110,"title":"Финансовый университет (бывш. ВГНА)"},{"id":111,"title":"ВГИК"},{"id":113,"title":"ВКШ МЭРТ"},{"id":114,"title":"ВТШ С. Мелконяна"},{"id":115,"title":"ВШ ГМУ"},{"id":116,"title":"ВШПП"},{"id":117,"title":"ВШП"},{"id":118,"title":"ВШСО"},{"id":119,"title":"ВТУ им. Щепкина"},{"id":120,"title":"ТИ им. Щукина (бывш. ВТУ им. Щукина)"},{"id":121,"title":"ВИУ"},{"id":122,"title":"ГАСИС"},{"id":123,"title":"ГАСК (МГУДТ)"},{"id":124,"title":"ГКА им. Маймонида (МГУДТ)"},{"id":125,"title":"Гос. ИРЯ им. Пушкина"},{"id":126,"title":"ГМПИ им. Ипполитова-Иванова"},{"id":127,"title":"РГСАИ (бывш. ГСИИ)"},{"id":128,"title":"НИУ ВШЭ (ГУ-ВШЭ)"},{"id":129,"title":"ГАУГН (бывш. ГУГН)"},{"id":130,"title":"ГУЗ"},{"id":131,"title":"ГУУ"},{"id":133,"title":"ГЭИ"},{"id":134,"title":"ГЭИТИ"},{"id":135,"title":"Гуманитарный институт"},{"id":136,"title":"ГИТР"},{"id":137,"title":"МГПИ (ныне МГПУ)"},{"id":138,"title":"ДА МИД РФ"},{"id":140,"title":"МОИУП"},{"id":141,"title":"Юринфор"},{"id":143,"title":"ИБП (до 2013 г.)"},{"id":144,"title":"ИБПМ"},{"id":145,"title":"МОИУ (бывш. ИБПИТ)"},{"id":146,"title":"ИБПУ"},{"id":147,"title":"РГИС (ВСК)"},{"id":148,"title":"ИГУ МГИМО МИД РФ"},{"id":149,"title":"ИГА"},{"id":150,"title":"ИГиМУ ГУУ"},{"id":151,"title":"ИГУМО"},{"id":152,"title":"ИДК"},{"id":154,"title":"ИНЕСНЭК"},{"id":155,"title":"ИЖЛТ"},{"id":156,"title":"ИИТЭМ"},{"id":157,"title":"ИИР"},{"id":158,"title":"ИК"},{"id":159,"title":"ИКиП"},{"id":160,"title":"ИКСИ АФСБ РФ"},{"id":161,"title":"ИМБО"},{"id":162,"title":"ИМПЭ им. Грибоедова"},{"id":163,"title":"ИМТП"},{"id":164,"title":"ИМЭС"},{"id":165,"title":"ИМПиПП"},{"id":166,"title":"ИМЭ"},{"id":168,"title":"ИМЭИ (мировой экономики и информатизации)"},{"id":169,"title":"ИПВ"},{"id":170,"title":"ИПО"},{"id":171,"title":"ИПП"},{"id":173,"title":"ИРЭСПиП"},{"id":174,"title":"ИСБ"},{"id":175,"title":"ИСИ"},{"id":176,"title":"ИСБТиСУ"},{"id":177,"title":"ИСН"},{"id":178,"title":"ИССО"},{"id":179,"title":"ИНЭКБИ"},{"id":180,"title":"ИЭиК"},{"id":181,"title":"ИЭП"},{"id":182,"title":"ИНЭП"},{"id":183,"title":"ИЭКП РАМА"},{"id":184,"title":"ИЭФП"},{"id":185,"title":"ИЭПиУР"},{"id":186,"title":"ИЯиК им. Л. Толстого"},{"id":188,"title":"ЛИ им. Горького"},{"id":189,"title":"МАТИ - РГТУ им. К. Э. Циолковского"},{"id":190,"title":"МВШ"},{"id":191,"title":"МИГМТ"},{"id":192,"title":"МИМ Линк"},{"id":193,"title":"МИЭП"},{"id":194,"title":"МНЭПУ"}]}
```

Для всего этого отлично подойдет Retrofit.

Также можно попробовать ВК-ную [Java-SDK](https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK)